# Error installing selenium 3.4

Tags: selenium

I have installed selenium 3.4 and configured in Eclipse.I have written a basic code and imported packages but this error is displayed in console

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
>     at com.nikhitha.practice.First.main(First.java:10)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have Firefox installed. Now you need to set the path for gecko driver binary like below. Make sure you `setProperty` before you initialize an object of Firefox driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/binary");
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In case you have not downloaded driver binary, please find binary [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

More details about gecko driver are available [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#selenium)